# How to select values between a XML tag in SQL Query

Tags: sql, regex, xml, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a table with CLOB column storing a XML. The structure of XML is unreadable. I want to get values between few tags like `<DOMAINID>`; sample is shown below.

*XML:*

```
<ID>
  <DOMAIN>IND<DOMAIN>
  <DOMAINID>112AC<DOMAINID>
<ID>
  
<GROUP>
  <GP>ASIA<GP>
  <RSN>GOOD<RSN>
<GROUP>
```

I am using this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'^.*<DOMAINID>(.*)</DOMAINID>.*$','\1',1,0,'mn') col1 FROM tab;
```

Expected result:

```
112AC
```

Actual XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<GML:GMMessage 
   xmlns:GML="GML" 
   xmlns:GMLType="GML.Type" 
   
   xsi:schemaLocation="GML ../schema/gml..xsd" SchemaVersion="9.8">
    <BusinessHdr>
       <busHdr:BusObjectType>ABC</busHdr:BusObjectType>
       <busHdr:BusObjectOwner>HDHDH</busHdr:BusObjectOwner>
       <busHdr:BusObjectId>DJHDAHDAJHDA</busHdr:BusObjectId>
       <busHdr:BusObjectVersion>1</busHdr:BusObjectVersion>
      </BusinessHdr>
    <Transaction>
     <GenericEvent>NEW</GenericEvent>
     <Group>
        <GroupId>3424234</GroupId>
        <Reason>MANUAL</Reason>
    </Group>
    < xsi:type="mm:MMIam">
       <Id>
           <Domain>ssdsgdsg</Domain>
           <DomainId>123456ACC</DomainId>
           <Version>1</Version>
       </Id>
       <Date>2021-02-01</Date>
     </Transaction>
    </GML:GMMessage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML; use a proper XML parser.

However, what you have is not properly formed XML as it is missing a root element and you are missing the `/` in all of the closing tags; so you first need to fix your XML and give it a root element and then you can parse it using an XML parser.

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '//root'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( '<root>' || t.data || '</root>' )
         COLUMNS
           domain   VARCHAR2(10) PATH './ID/DOMAIN',
           domainid VARCHAR2(10) PATH './ID/DOMAINID',
           gp       VARCHAR2(50) PATH './GROUP/GP',
           rsn      VARCHAR2(50) PATH './GROUP/RSN'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( data ) AS
SELECT '<ID>
  <DOMAIN>IND</DOMAIN>
  <DOMAINID>112AC</DOMAINID>
</ID>
<GROUP>
  <GP>ASIA</GP>
  <RSN>GOOD</RSN>
</GROUP>' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DOMAIN | DOMAINID | GP   | RSN 
> :----- | :------- | :--- | :---
> IND    | 112AC    | ASIA | GOOD
> ```

If you just want a single value then you can use `XMLQUERY`:

```sql
SELECT  XMLQUERY(
          '/root/ID/DOMAINID/text()'
          PASSING XMLTYPE( '<root>'||data||'</root>' )
          RETURNING CONTENT
        ) AS domainid
FROM    table_name
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | DOMAINID |
> | :------- |
> | 112AC    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c06a896ae9fb48da10bed3c6d8ba28a)*

---

## Update

I am going to assume that your XML also defines the `xsi` and `busHdr` namespaces (if it doesn't then Oracle will fail to parse the XML as it does not know what those namespaces are); that would give you this sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( data ) AS
SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<GML:GMMessage 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:GML="GML" 
   xmlns:busHdr="busHdr"
   xmlns:GMLType="GML.Type"
   
   xsi:schemaLocation="GML ../schema/gml.xsd busHdr ../schema/bushdr.xsd"
   SchemaVersion="9.8">
    <BusinessHdr>
       <busHdr:BusObjectType>ABC</busHdr:BusObjectType>
       <busHdr:BusObjectOwner>HDHDH</busHdr:BusObjectOwner>
       <busHdr:BusObjectId>DJHDAHDAJHDA</busHdr:BusObjectId>
       <busHdr:BusObjectVersion>1</busHdr:BusObjectVersion>
      </BusinessHdr>
    <Transaction>
     <GenericEvent>NEW</GenericEvent>
     <Group>
        <GroupId>3424234</GroupId>
        <Reason>MANUAL</Reason>
    </Group>
       <Id>
           <Domain>ssdsgdsg</Domain>
           <DomainId>123456ACC</DomainId>
           <Version>1</Version>
       </Id>
       <Date>2021-02-01</Date>
     </Transaction>
    </GML:GMMessage>' FROM DUAL
```

Then, you just need to add the namespace that you are using and update the paths to the new (case-sensitive) locations:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES( 'GML' AS "GML" ),
         '//GML:GMMessage/Transaction'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.data )
         COLUMNS
           domain   VARCHAR2(10) PATH './Id/Domain',
           domainid VARCHAR2(10) PATH './Id/DomainId',
           version  NUMBER(3,0)  PATH './Id/Version',
           groupid  VARCHAR2(50) PATH './Group/GroupId',
           reason   VARCHAR2(50) PATH './Group/Reason',
           dt       DATE         PATH './Date'
       ) x
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DOMAIN   | DOMAINID  | VERSION | GROUPID | REASON | DT       
> :------- | :-------- | ------: | :------ | :----- | :--------
> ssdsgdsg | 123456ACC |       1 | 3424234 | MANUAL | 01-FEB-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c5ba692e3b126cb073d5f463344d021)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this doesnt work since i have Oracle 11g. Its giving 
`ORA-00905: missing keyword` . Can you please suggest ?

Comment: @vnsingh On Oracle 11g, use `CROSS JOIN` rather than `CROSS APPLY` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41818a5b984c49f9c735a56d69d17554).

Comment: Am not sure what path i need to put here, My XML looks like <example in question>

Comment: Thanks @MTO. Not wokring with me since something wrong with database but this looks promising,

Answer (score -1):

Good to see your thinking with your approach...

Would suggest checking out this tool (if you haven't got a similar one) to help you with Regular expressions https://regexr.com/, helps me a lot.

You're SQL looks right (using the "m" and "n" flag for multiline), but not sure if it's your XML was typed in wrong, since you're regex string doesn't work on the XML you pasted, but I did get it work if it's XML.

What is you're current output from your SQL?  you might need to use `$1` in place of your `\1`.

I would also suggest

1. perhaps also escaping your forward slash, as that might be your culprit.
2. add more specificity to your capture to stop your search from being greedy.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'^.*<DOMAINID>([0-9A-z]+)<\/DOMAINID>.*$','$1',1,0,'mn') col1 FROM tab;
```

Comment: Here am just getting Numeric part but alphabets are missing. Can you please check ? getting `112` but need `112AC`